# Copy Column and append string using SQL

Tags: sql, string

Hey I was trying to use the following to copy Usernames in a Wordpress database, into the email field;

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET user_email = (
    SELECT user_login
    FROM wp_users
    WHERE wp_users.id = wp_users.id
);
```

But, it looks like i cannot update using data from the same table, i receive;

```
Error in query (1093): You can't specify target table 'wp_users' for update in FROM clause
```

im not sure how i add @domain.com onto the end of the user_email, when it contains the data from user_login.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the databse you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET user_email = user_login
```

To make email (MySql):

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET user_email = concat(user_login, '@domain.com')
```

To make email (SQL Server):

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET user_email = user_login + '@domain.com'
```

Comment: Hey, your right that is simpler, the first part worked correctly, however second is giving me this;

    Error in query (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '@thedomain.com'

I will try to research also.

Comment: It is probably `concat(user_login, '@domain.com'`).  The only database that would give the specified error is MySQL.

Comment: It worked, perfect guys thanks. feel free to update and ill accept!